# Virtual Machine display in Mac

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm using ORACLE Virtualbox in my Mac, I get two problems when running a VM

1. The Display is shrunk, it doesn't occupy the complete screen even at Full Screen Mode.
2. When mouse is captured in the VM I'm unable to move it out of VM, when I'm not in Full Screen Mode.

I'm not sure why this happens

Comment: Press ctrl alt or command alt to go out of the VM.

Comment: thanks.. but why does vm doesn't use the complete screen, I get only display half the screen in width, for height I've to scroll the virtual box  scroll bar

Comment: Click `Devices` and install the Guest Additions CD-ROM, then go in your Virtual Machine and run the *Guest Additions* setup. Then reboot your VM.